# Return to for loop from errorhandler in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How to return from Errorhandler in VBA to for loop?

```
for x = 1 to 1000
  On error goto errorhandler
  Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B") = x * Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value
continue:
Next

Exit sub

Errorhandler:
  Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x,"B") = "Error occured"
  Resume continue
```

This doesn't work. I want that if error happens in the for loop, it will write in the cell "Error occured" and and then continue the loop. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "This doesn't work"?  It certainly does what you expect it to do when I test in Excel 2010.

Comment: This is really not difficult to find on Google!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I typed wrong number in the for loop but now it works. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

```
On Error GoTo Errorhandler 'put once, outside loop
    For x = 1 To 1000
    'use value2 if you dont work with date/time
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B").Value2 = x * Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value2
    Next

    Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B").Value2 = "Error occured"
    Resume Next '<< Answer to original question. The Resume to continue label should also work
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works when I test it, so I am not sure what specific problem you're encountering, however you can consider refactoring the code to avoid `GoTo` statements, which will improve its readability:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Long
Dim val

For x = 1 To 1000
    On Error Resume Next
    val = x * Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B") = "Error occured"
    Else:
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B") = val
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I think in choosing between an in-line error handler (shown here) and one separate from the execution of normal code a stylistic choice that, for me, is based on how frequently I expect an error.  If I get errors frequently, I would use in-line.  If I almost never get errors, I would use a separate block.

Comment: @CodeJockey Sure, and I do use both types of handling, but as a general rule I think anything that can avoid the spaghetti-fication of code is preferable, and sometimes this even means creating a subroutine/function for this operation so that the error occurs and is handled entirely in the called procedure.